# How can I setup my WiiMote as mouse?

Tags: mouse, wii

I recently saw a video how a guy used his WiiMote as mouse for his computer. Since I have a media center PC and a Wii, it would be great to get rid of peripherals and just use the WiiMote as my mouse. How can I set that up?

Note: You should not only be able to use the buttons, but also move the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [WiiCan](https://launchpad.net/wiican). It sounds like it would be able to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I can also google. What I am looking for is a step-by-step guide how to set-up-your Wii as mouse.